# Matlab, values over specific y-range

Tags: matlab, intervals

In MATLAB, I would like to know what the best way is to get the `x`-range values over an specific `y`-range.

For example, if I have a graph of fluctuating temperature (`y`-axis) with respect to time (`x`-axis), I want to know how many times the temperature is above 550°C but below 600°C.
The temperature fluctuates over time, so many intervals between these temperatures can be found along the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
T = rand(100,1); %Your temperature variable
c = (T > 0.2) & (T < 0.8); %Your threshholds, in your case switch the 0.2 for 550 and the 0.8 for 600
sum(diff([0; c]) == 1)
```

What's happening here is this:
`c = (T > 0.2) & (T < 0.8)` creates a mask where points that are between your threshholds are `1` and points that are outside are `0`. Now `diff` finds the difference between each adjacent point so for example `diff([1 0 0 1 1 1 0])` will return `-1   0   1   0   0  -1` but we only want to count each time our `c` vector goes from `0` to `1` (or we could count it going from `1` to `0`, so long as we don't count both) hence the `== 1`. Finally we don't want to miss a gorup of ones starting at the beginning hence we add a `0` to the beginning.

**EDIT:**

Based on your comment and assuming you have a time vector called `x` and a temperature vector called `y`:

```
dx = x(2)-x(1) %I'm assuming this remains constant throughout x, i.e. x(n) - x(n-1) is constant
mask = (y >= 550) & (y <= 600)
totalTime = sum(mask)*dx
```

If the time differences in `x` are not constant then do this:

```
mask = (y >= 550) & (y <= 600)
dx = x(end) - x(end-1);
d = -diff([0;mask;0]).*[x; x(end)+dx];
totalTime = sum(d)
```

Comment: could also use `length(find(c))`?

Comment: @TryHard That finds something different, though perhaps it is what the OP wants. I was finding how many times the temperature moves into the range, you are finding how many points fall within the range. It is unclear which the OP is after.

Comment: What i'm looking for is the time where the graph goes beyond an specif value, for example if there are three intervals of 20 seconds where the temperature is 550<T<600 in the graph i would like to know the total time (60 sec)

Comment: substitute the `sum` bit with `length(find(c))` and you have the number of entries that fell within the range...

Comment: And what if the difference between values of the time vector are not equal is there some way to mitigate this?